# Erorr in installing Juice UI package

Tags: visual-studio-2012, juice-ui

I wanna install Juice UI, but I faced with complicated problem.
My OS is 'Windows seven Ultimate'and I 'm using Visual Studio 2012 with NuGet Package Manager   2.0.30625.9003
and dotNetFrame work 4.5, anyway I tried Tools>Extension and Updates and command prompt (PM> Install-Package JuiceUI) to install juice, but in both cases I got this error:

```
**PM> Install-Package JuiceUI
Attempting to resolve dependency 'jQuery (≥ 1.8.2)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'jQuery.UI.Combined (≥ 1.9.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'json2'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'AmplifyJS'.
Successfully installed 'jQuery 1.8.3'.
Successfully installed 'jQuery.UI.Combined 1.9.2'.
Successfully installed 'json2 1.0.2'.
Successfully installed 'AmplifyJS 1.1.0'.
Successfully installed 'JuiceUI 1.1.1'.
Successfully added 'jQuery 1.8.3' to jame-jam.
Successfully added 'jQuery.UI.Combined 1.9.2' to jame-jam.
Successfully added 'json2 1.0.2' to jame-jam.
Successfully added 'AmplifyJS 1.1.0' to jame-jam.
Successfully uninstalled 'JuiceUI 1.1.1'.
Successfully uninstalled 'AmplifyJS 1.1.0'.
Successfully uninstalled '***json2*** 1.0.2'.
Successfully uninstalled 'jQuery.UI.Combined 1.9.2'.
Successfully uninstalled 'jQuery 1.8.3'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'JuiceUI 1.1.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that
 targets '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible wit
h that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  JuiceUI
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand**
```

---

I wonder if somebody help me in solving this issue!
I guess it needs DotNetframeWork 3.5, but as you know 3.5 isn't for Windows 7 and Juice UI works in visual studio 2010 and later. So I utterly mixed up, what should I do!?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is explained in the error message itself -

Install-Package : Could not install package 'JuiceUI 1.1.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that
 **targets '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5'**

juiceUI doesn't work below 4.0. change your project settings to work with .Net 4.0